# Why is keyboard and touchpad not working without Wi-Fi?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, wifi, trackpad

My Mac (early 2015, High Sierra) suddenly started blocking off the built-in keyboard and touchpad if it's not connected to wi-fi at startup/wake-up. (This means I can't connect to any public WiFi with a login screen, which is super annoying). If it's connected, everything works fine.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Test this in Safe Mode (boot holding Shift]. Does the problem continue?  Don’t do what @Thinkr suggested unless you have an external keyboard attached as you won’t be able to use the keyboard again until you force power down your Mac.